# Getting model name from model instance YII

Tags: php, yii

How can i get model name from model instance.
For e.x.

$model=new State;

here,
State is model
$model is State model instance.

I want to get model name i.e State from $model i.e model instance.

Comment: Working example with explanation: http://code2real.blogspot.in/2015/06/yii-11-get-current-model-name.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

get_class() — Returns the name of the class of an object

string get_class ([ object $object ] )

therefore you use it like this: $modelname=get_class($modelinstance);

->it returns a string.

Comment: I much prefer this method. There's no need to extend the model as get_class is built into php http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Comment: This one is more efficient, in case you have 12 models, we cannot write 12 functions to get their names.

Comment: if your class is in some namespace, one might use basename(get_class($object))

Answer (score 15):

add this method to your State Class

```
public function getModelName()
{
    return __CLASS__;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$model = new State();
echo $model->getModelName();
```

Comment: Hi @Wager, Also I prefer toninoj more, why don't you accept an answer as true right now?

Answer (score 1):

Use this PHP method : `get_class`

```
 print get_class($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Item extends CActiveRecord
{

    public function getBaseModelName()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    public function getCalledClassName()
    {
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class Product extends Item {}

class Service extends Item {}

class ProductController extends CController
{
    $model = new Product;
    echo $model->baseModelName; // Item
}

class ServiceController extends CController
{
    $model = new Service;

    echo $model->calledClassName; // Service 
    echo get_class($model); // Service 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get State as the question asked, you may do this : -

```
basename(get_class($model))
```